# Trouble using gsl/gsl, from brew, on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker, gsl

1. `brew install gsl` - no trouble
2. quickly make a Mac app which uses gsl, to check it is working. ([Handy example here.](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC210/gsl/gsl.html)) - no trouble
3. are they there in /include and /lib - yes they are

[image]

4. both search paths?  yes and marked recursive

[image]

5. linker flags? set as many as possible

[image]

6. Delete derived data, clean everything, restart everything

Result .......

[image]

file not found :/

What to do about this tragedy?

Comment: Just see that you showed that gsl exists, but not gsl/gsl. So, does gsl/gsl exists?

Comment: On your snapshot, you showed that gsl is -> ../Cellar/gsl/2.5/include/gsl. I'm asking if this file exists: ../Cellar/gsl/2.5/include/gsl/gsl

Comment: MY GOD - you're right !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: for example, `#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>` works fine ............

Comment: Glad to see that it solves your problem :D

Comment: Note that even once you get the header files sorted, you still won't be able to link against the gsl dylib installed by Homebrew for a (non-simulator) iOS application, as it's a different architecture. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755160/gnu-scientific-library-in-ios for how to build for iOS – though unfortunately the answers are quite old, so I don't know if they'll still work.

Comment: Thanks, but I will not put an answer. Anyway, you can always look at the source of GSL: https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL

Comment: ah!  of course ...  thanks @hamish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of anyone googling here, user @Amadeus solved the issue:

- the `brew install gsl` build does not include /gsl as such
- you can indeed `#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>` or any other

However!

- As @Hamish pointed out - unfortunately that build does not include iOS architecture anyway :/

Comment: Just came across this and I think there is some deeper confusion at play here: There are two different "GSL"s. One is the Gnu Scientific Library which is a C library and includes e.g. a BLAS implementation, the other one is (as mentioned in another comment) the Guidelines Support Library which is a C++ library that has nothing to do with BLAS, but is normally included as `#include <gsl/gsl>`. I don't think the C GSL is ever included without the `.h`.